# In android material design do I have to give any specific style attribute to an already material theme?

Tags: java, android, styles, material-design

I have specified a theme of material design in my app.

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material"`

I have just read some documentation about material design from google site.

https://material.google.com/

My question is that do I follow the design guidelines which i read in the site above to the tee although i have implemented the material design theme in my manifest file.

In simpler terms do i have to do any individual "material" styling to any view widget when i have implemented `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material"` in my manifest file.

Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here.

It seems that i have to individually apply styling and animation to the corresponding view.

For eg just to show that a view is above its parent layout i have to give a style attribute "elevation".This attribute is not supported in other themes than material theme.

Another eg.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/myview"
...
android:elevation="2dp"
android:background="@drawable/myrect" />
```